# undefined symbol OBJC_CLASS_$_BLNetwork

Tags: ios, objective-c

_OBJC_CLASS_$_BLNetwork

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BLNetwork", referenced from:
[image]
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in AuxDashBoardViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DeviceListViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AuxSettingsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AuxConfigViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You should try this in real device not in simulator

Comment: Yes, correct. in the real device, it's working fine but I want to run in the simulator as well. May I know the issue please and solution as well.

Comment: x86_64 is simulator architecture and it does not supported by some library

Comment: is there any alternate way run in the simulator?

Comment: Sorry not aware about it :(